# Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

"*Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin*" error in Android Studio

Version information:
Android Studio 1.5, JDK 1.8, API 23, NDK 10e,
Gradle 2.9, gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha3

Comment: You should upgrade your Android Studio. It's too old.

Comment: Well, the codebase is kind of old, so I cannot just move to latest Android Studio. More problems arise.